# NodeJS CoffeeScript external file scope

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

How does one define a function in one file (`a.coffee`), so that a NodeJS module in another file (`b.coffee`) can use it?

For example:

```
# a.coffee
b = require('./b')

getGreeting = (name) ->
  if name == "foo"
    "Hey, "
  else
    "Hello, "


b.greet "foo"



# b.coffee
module.exports =
  greet: (name) ->
    greeting = getGreeting name
    console.log greeting + name
```

Compiling this with `coffee -bc *.coffee` and running with `nodejs a.js` gives

```
ReferenceError: getGreeting is not defined
    at Object.module.exports.greet (/home/charlie/Desktop/NodeJSExtTest/b.js:5:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/charlie/Desktop/NodeJSExtTest/a.js:14:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:142:18)
    at node.js:939:3
```

I've also tried to use `@getGreeting`, but with the same result.

Extra information:

```
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.10.0

$ nodejs -v
v5.9.1
```

Comment: b.coffee has no reference to getGreeting

Comment: @eosterberg I get that, but how would I give b that reference? For now, I'm doing in a: `(eval b.greet.toString())("foo")`, but that's just asking for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inject `getGreeting` into module b e.g. as follows:

b.coffee:

```
module.exports = (getGreeting) ->
  greet: (name) ->
    greeting = getGreeting name
    console.log greeting + name
```

a.coffee:

```
b = require('./b')(getGreeting)
```

Comment: Will this work too if the function `getGreeting` requires more variables from `a.coffee`? I want to split my main file in more smaller files, but they all need these variables, and they keep changing

Comment: Yes. The exterior function in the module `b`'s code (`(getGreeting) -> greet: ...`) is executed like any other function within module `a`, and JavaScript's normal scoping rules apply for any function it may receives as an argument. So you can have something along these lines in module `a`: `title = 'Mr. '; getGreeting = (name) -> if name == 'foo' then 'Hey, ' + title else 'Hello, ' + title`, then `b = require('./b')(getGreeting)`.